# failed to execute "bash": bash: ./instance_status.sh: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, shell, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a bash script , instance_status.sh which have all the access permission , this script is placed in / , when i try to execute it throws below error

```
Error: failed to execute "bash": bash: ./instance_status.sh: No such file or directory

on main.tf line 38, in data "external" "instance_status":
38: data "external" "instance_status" {
```

Bash Script :

```
 #!/bin/bash

 set -e

 eval "$(jq -r '@sh "INSTANCE_ID=\(.id)"')"

sleep 360

status=$(aws ec2 describe-instance-status --instance-ids ${INSTANCE_ID} --output json --query 
'InstanceStatuses[0]')

instance_status=$(echo ${status} | jq -r '.InstanceStatus.Details[0].Status')
system_status=$(echo ${status} | jq -r '.SystemStatus.Details[0].Status')

jq -n --arg inst_status "$instance_status" \
  --arg sys_status "$system_status" \
  '{"instance_status":$inst_status,"system_status":$sys_status}'
```

I am calling bash script from below terrafrom main.tf file :

```
data "external" "instance_status" {

program = ["bash", "${path.module}/instance_status.sh"]

query = {
id = aws_instance.QA-server-via-ami.id
}
}

output "test" {
value = data.external.instance_status.result
}
```

Could you please assist .

Comment: Why do you use `bash` to launch a script? I always use `sh`, and let the first line in the script (`#!/bin/bash`) decide which shell to use.

Comment: @Dominique, if you use `sh myscript`, then the shebang line is just a comment, and your script is run with the "sh" interpreter. To really use the shebang line, you must let the OS handle the script: `chmod a+x myscript; ./myscript` -- see your system's `execve` man page.

Comment: @antik, what's in `${path.module}`? Apparently "instance_status.sh" is not there.

Comment: If the script is in `/`, you must call it like this `/instance_status.sh`.  If you call it with `./instance_status.sh`, it is trying to find the script in the current directory, described by `.`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"this script is placed in /" so use absolute path:

```
/instance_status.sh
```